# Obtaining SignalR Hub without losing its clients from "other place in code"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have app for one person that has to display data on webpage from external device connected via usb port

Before, I gave user button "Start listening" that sent http request to backend which started listening on port (and blocked app, but it was fine because it is supposed to be used by exactly 1 person at time) until it received not-error response (`SerialDataReceivedEvent`/`SerialErrorReceivedEvent`)
and `SerialData` was returned from that request and displayed on page

I have to rewrite this using SignalR, so I quickly came with naive solution like this:

```
public class DeviceReaderHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    // this is static because listening that port (SerialPort) has to stay open
    private static DeviceReader_Helper _service;

    public DeviceReaderHub(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;

        if (_service == null)
        {
            _service = new DeviceReader_Helper();
            _service.Open(_config["DeviceInfo:Port"]);
        }

        _service.DataReceived_Delegate = SendMessage;
        _service.ErrorReceived_Delegate = SendErrorMessage;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("onRead", message);
    }

    public async Task SendErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("onRead", $"error = {message}");
    }

    public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("onConnected");
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

but I received reality-check very quickly - I cannot do it like that because `DeviceReaderHub` is disposed.

> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll

I thought about obtaining new `DeviceReaderHub` hub whenever `SerialDataReceivedEvent` or `SerialErrorReceivedEvent` is being Invoked
but I have not idea how can I get instance of the hub without losing connected clients

Comment: Your question is unclear. The object ```DeviceReader_Helper _service``` is throwing the dispose exception?

Comment: @Kiril1512 delegate `DataReceived_Delegate` which I want to execute `SendMessage` from `DeviceReaderHub`_____________________`_service.DataReceived_Delegate = SendMessage; _service.ErrorReceived_Delegate = SendErrorMessage;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR hubs are transient objects, which means that a new hub instance is used for *each method call* on the hub from the client. According to [this Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-and-use-hubs):

> Don't store state in a property on the hub class. Every hub method call is executed on a new hub instance.

So you should not use the hub to do anything other than receiving and handling requests from the client. To send messages to the client outside of the hub, SignalR provides the `HubContext<T>` class which is available from Dependency Injection. For example:

```
public class DeviceReader_Helper {

    private readonly IHubContext<DeviceReaderHub> _hubContext;

    // you can obtain hubContext either from constructor DI, or service locator pattern with an IServiceProvider
    public DeviceReader_Helper(IHubContext<DeviceReaderHub> hubContext) {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message) {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("onRead", message);
    }
}
```

For more information see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1). As for your concern that

> but I have not idea how can I get instance of the hub without losing connected clients

Clients can be connected without a hub instance. Hubs are only used to receive messages from the client, and are not necessary to keep a client connected to the server.

Comment: works fine, thanks. 
 `DataReceived_Delegate = async (string message) =>
 {
  var service = (IHubContext<CardReaderHub>)provider.GetService(typeof(IHubContext<CardReaderHub>));
  await service.Clients.All.SendAsync("onRead", message);
 };`